# How to do phrase search using sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

I need to create phrase search using sphinx. I created my index using this config file

```
source sphinx_search
{
    type                                    = mysql
    # some straightforward parameters for SQL source types
    sql_host                                = localhost
    sql_user                                = root
    sql_pass                                = root
    sql_db                                  = mydatabase
    sql_port                                = 3306

    sql_query                       = \
        SELECT userId, usertype_id, searchdata from tbl_user;

    #sql_attr_uint                       = userId
    sql_attr_uint                       = usertype_id

     #document info query, ONLY for CLI search (ie. testing and debugging)
     #optional, default is empty
     #must contain $id macro and must fetch the document by that id
    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE userId=$id;

}
index sphinx_search {
    source                          = sphinx_search
    path                            = /var/lib/sphinx/sphinx_search
    morphology                      = stem_en
    min_stemming_len        = 4
    stopwords                       = /var/data/sphinx/stopwords.txt
    min_word_len            = 3
    min_prefix_len          = 3
    min_infix_len           = 0
    enable_star                     = 1
    phrase_boundary = ., ?, !, U+2026 # horizontal ellipsis
    phrase_boundary_step = 100
    html_strip = 1

} 

indexer {
    mem_limit = 256M    
   #mem_limit       = 128M
    max_xmlpipe2_field = 16M 
}


searchd {   
    compat_sphinxql_magics  = 0     
    listen          = 9312  
    listen          = 9306:mysql41  
    log         = /var/log/sphinx/searchd.log   
    query_log       = /var/log/sphinx/query.log     
    read_timeout        = 5     
    max_children        = 30    
    pid_file        = /var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid   
    max_matches     = 10000     
    seamless_rotate     = 1     
    preopen_indexes     = 1     
    unlink_old      = 1     
    workers     = threads # for RT to work  
    binlog_path     = /var/data/ 
}
```

If I tried to search for "Water Pollution" word

The search result is showing like this

```
words:
1. 'water': 10554 documents, 37143 hits
2. 'pollut': 1902 documents, 9657 hits
```

First issue is its not taking that "pollution" word completely Instead of that its taking "pollut".

Second problem is its not searching for that complete word. Even if I search

> "water pollution" 
>   like this.

third problem I am unable to sort my result with userId. If I tried to add

> sql_attr_uint                       = userId

its not indexing properly.

Any body can help me to fix these issues. Please help me.

Comment: Please show the code of search request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell you have to set extended match mode and use [extended query syntax](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax):

```
$cl->SetMatchMode ( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED );
$cl->Query ( '"Water pollution"' );
```

Notice double quotes around search term.